# Why does this oracle select statement take minutes to complete?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

These tables have less than 20 fields, properties has about 9 million rows while listings has 3 million rows, but that should not be a problem.  This is what databases are for...

the listing_ids are of type Number.  Our best guess so far is that because the properties table has 6 million more rows with listingids that dont actually point to a listing, Oracle spends a lot of time looking for listings that dont exist.  Does that even make sense?

```
Select  count(*) 
from listings.rfs_listings listings  
    join listings.rfs_properties properties 
        on listings.listing_id= properties.listing_id        
where listings.display = 1  
    and properties.city= 'New York'
    and rownum <= 10;
```

I ran an explain plan on the query and got the following info:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

Plan hash value: 772088252

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                             |    10 |  4110 |   283   (0)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS               |                             |    10 |  4110 |   283   (0)| 00:00:04 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | RFS_LISTINGS                |   140 |  2940 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | RFS_PROPERTIES_LD730_UNIQUE |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RFS_PROPERTIES              |     1 |   390 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
   4 - filter("LISTINGS"."DISPLAY"=1)
   5 - access("LISTINGS"."LISTING_ID"="PROPERTIES"."LISTING_ID")
   6 - filter(NLSSORT("PROPERTIES"."CITY",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI''')=HEXTORAW('6E657720796F726
      B00') )
```

EDIT:  Table Schemas:

```
rfs.rfs_listings:
Name                            Null?    Type
------------------------------- -------- ------------------
DETAIL_ID                       NOT NULL NUMBER
LISTING_ID                      NOT NULL NUMBER
DETAIL_CHECKSUM                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
PRICE                                    NUMBER
IN_CONTRACT                     NOT NULL NUMBER
CREATED                         NOT NULL DATE
PROPERTY_WEB_ID                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
SOURCE_ID                       NOT NULL NUMBER
LISTING_CREATED                 NOT NULL DATE
ARCHIVE_NAME                             VARCHAR2(100)
DUPLICATES_GROUP_ID                      NUMBER
FILENAME                                 VARCHAR2(80)
DISPLAY                                  NUMBER


rfs.rfs_properties:
Name                             Null?    Type
------------------------------- -------- -----------------
PROPERTY_ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER
LISTING_ID                      NOT NULL NUMBER
BLDG_PROPKEY                             NUMBER
UNIT_PROPKEY                             NUMBER
ADDRESSKEY                               NUMBER
HOUSE_NUMBER                             VARCHAR2(32)
STREET_ADDRESS                           VARCHAR2(200)
UNIT_NUMBER                              VARCHAR2(32)
UNIT_NUMBER_PARSED                       VARCHAR2(16 CHAR)
PARSED_ADDRESS                           VARCHAR2(255)
DISPLAY_ADDRESS                          VARCHAR2(150)
CROSS_STREET                             VARCHAR2(200)
NEIGHBORHOOD                             VARCHAR2(150)
NEIGHBORHOOD_CODE                        NUMBER
NEIGHBORHOOD_REG_CODE                    NUMBER
SCHOOL_DISTRICT                          VARCHAR2(100)
BOROUGH_CITY                             VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
METRO_AREA                               VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
ZIP_CODE                                 NUMBER
COUNTY                                   NUMBER
STATE                                    VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)
ROOMS                                    NUMBER
BEDROOMS                                 NUMBER
BATHROOMS                                NUMBER
SQFT                                     NUMBER
LOT_SIZE                                 NUMBER
STUDIO                                   NUMBER
LOFT                                     NUMBER
MAINT_CC                                 NUMBER
RE_TAX                                   NUMBER
PROPERTY_TYPE_ID                         NUMBER
PROPERTY_TYPE                            VARCHAR2(255)
BLDG_NAME                                VARCHAR2(255)
BLDG_TYPE                                VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
BLDG_NEW_DEVEL                           NUMBER
BLDG_FEATURES                            VARCHAR2(256)
MANUALLY_BLDG_FEAT                       VARCHAR2(255)
APT_FEATURES                             VARCHAR2(256)
OUTDOOR_SPACE                            VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
YEAR_BUILT                               NUMBER
LISTING_RANK                    NOT NULL NUMBER
LOCATION_CHECKED                         NUMBER
PROPKEY_SOURCE                           VARCHAR2(15)
WEB_BUG_URL                              VARCHAR2(255)
EMAIL_LEAD_GENERATION                    VARCHAR2(100)
LISTING_URL                              VARCHAR2(255)
BROKER_NAME                              VARCHAR2(100)
BROKER_URL                               VARCHAR2(256)
LISTING_TEXT                             CLOB
IS_UPDATED                               NUMBER
CENTROID_X                               NUMBER(20,10)
CENTROID_Y                               NUMBER(20,10)
CENTROID                                 MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
COUNTY_GEO_ID                            NUMBER
CX                                       NUMBER
CY                                       NUMBER
```

Some updated Statistics after updating oracle stats:

### Statistics

```
     31  recursive calls
      2  db block gets
  63053  consistent gets
  15474  physical reads
      0  redo size
   2890  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    524  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
     10  rows processed
```

New Execution Plan After Updating Statistics:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3213592672

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                             |    10 |  4110 |   236   (0)| 00:00:03 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                 |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                 |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                             |    10 |  4110 |   236   (0)| 00:00:03 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RFS_LISTINGS                |   224 |  4704 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RFS_LISTINGS_DISPLAY        |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | RFS_PROPERTIES_LD730_UNIQUE |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | RFS_PROPERTIES              |     1 |   390 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
   5 - access("LISTINGS"."DISPLAY"=1)
   6 - access("LISTINGS"."LISTING_ID"="PROPERTIES"."LISTING_ID")
   7 - filter(NLSSORT("PROPERTIES"."BOROUGH_CITY",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI''')=HEXTORAW('6E657720796F726B
          00') )
```

Comment: Need more info on the schema, indexes, etc.

Comment: Your query plan indicates that Oracle is starting with the RFS_LISTINGS table and then looking up RFS_PROPERTIES, so it is not "looking for listings that dont exist" as you suspected.  However, a data model that has a "foreign key" where 6M out of 9M rows have an invalid reference **is** rather broken!

Comment: We still need to know what indexes exist.  Also, how many 'New York' properties are there, and how many listings with display = 1?

Comment: For rfs_listings there is an index on:

price, listing_id, and display.

For rfs_properties there is an index on 39 of the fields, I can list them all if you want, but listing_id is included.

Comment: OK, but (a) how many 'New York' properties are there? (b) how many listings with display = 1 (c) is there an index on properties.city?

Comment: 1952 Rows in 'New York', 2028855 Rows with display = 1, yes

Answer (score 7):

Your query plan suggests that Oracle believes there are 140 rows in RFS_LISTINGS where DISPLAY=1, not millions.  To get better optimisation you need to gather some better stats.

To clarify, I mean you should run the [DBMS_STATS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII) package so that Oracle (not just you) knows how much data it is dealing with e.g.:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats ('LISTINGS');
```

Talk to your DBA first.

Comment: rfs_listings has 2527011, while rfs_properties has 9024600.  How do I updated the stats?  

    EXEC dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(’listings’, cascade=>TRUE); ?

How long should this take?

Comment: Yes but Oracle believes it has 140, and needs to be advised differently - see my updated answer.

Comment: This sounds right.  My understanding is that oracle uses these statistics to build the most efficient selection method, and if they are incorrect it wont choose correctly?

Comment: Correct.  If it thinks there are only 140 rows then it probably thinks a full table scan will require only a coupe of reads, and is therefore the best way to find any row in that table, and that any indexes add no benefit.

Comment: After speaking with the DBA, he said the 140 only shows the number of rows selected within that part of the process, and that it doesn't represent the complete number of rows in the table.  We ran the gather_schema_stats and it didn't help our case.  It now displays 246 rows in the plan.  The query takes 2:46:00 now.

Comment: Yes, he's right, I was wrong about what that 140 meant, sorry.  So, Oracle believes that there are about 246 rows in Listing that match the condition DISPLAY=1.  Is it about right, or is the answer really in the millions?

Comment: 1952 Rows in 'New York'
2028855 Rows with display = 1

Comment: OK, so your query cries out to use an index on properties.city to get the 1952 New York properties, and then do 1952 index lookups on listings.  But it doesn't because it thinks there are only 246 listings with display=1 and presumably thinks listings is much smaller than it really is.  Why?  What does this return: `select num_rows from all_tables where owner='LISTINGS' and table_name = 'RFS_LISTINGS';`?

Answer (score 2):

you will want indexing on the WHERE columns...

```
listings.display = 1  
properties.city= 'New York'
```

Comment: I'd qualify: "you **might** want...".  If 2M out of 3M rows in listings have display=1 then it probably wouldn't help.

Comment: It definitely helped, now down to around 30 seconds.  But that is still unacceptable.

Comment: Did you create one index with those two fields, or two separate indexes?  If you created a single index, make sure the most restrictive clause (`poperties.city`) is the first element.  I don't remember if you need to re-collect your statistics after creating an index in Oracle, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Jared, I suggest you post the new execution plan after creating more indexes.

Comment: added new execution plan to OP

Answer (score 0):

Could be because `ROWNUM` is evaluated after all data is selected. Plus, as Randy said, you're gonna need indexes, but by the plan, it looks like you have them.

Comment: nah rownum isn't usually included, and is kind of irrelevant here.  I shouldn't have included it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is an index for LISTING_ID on each table.  This should prevent the full table scan from occurring.

Comment: If you would list your current indexes, then we can all stop shooting in the dark on which ones you might need.